# Writing a list to a CSV un Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have this code for writing a list to a CSV file, but when I run it, it creates spaces between each of the lines I want to write. To show you, this is my code:

```
savelst = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(savelst)
```

and it gives me this result:

```
1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5
```

So I don't want the space in between.

Comment: Use the binary mode `wb`

Comment: Strange. I just ran your code using `Python 3.6.1` and I did not get any whitespace between the lines. Which version did you use?

Comment: I used python 3.6 as well. But I already solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line where you open the file as:

```
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
```

Adding the newline argument as '' will remove the new lines from your output file.

Comment: In fact it removes the additional newline.

Comment: I meant new lines, but I wrote spaces there by mistake. Corrected it now.